# SELECT QUERY FOR MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name `sample_table` and it is having multiple columns but I need to select two columns name `NAME` and `DATE` from this table and `DATE` field can be `NULL`or`0000-00-00`.

But I need all records for `NAME` and `where date is NULL or 0000-00-00` query returns 0 against that name.

Please help and thanks in advance.

I mean this date is `completion_date` and i want `0` everywhere , where there is no record of `completion date` against `name` for `ex -`

```
Name Date
Ram Null
Shyam 0000-00-00
Heena 2015-12-23
```

expected result will be -

```
Ram - 0
Shyam - 0
Heena - 1
```

Comment: Put the query you tried, input and expected output;

Comment: apart from `null` and `0000-00-00` does your date column have any other `real dates`?

Comment: Looking at your question `a simple select statement` shall do your job. Till you post what you have tried so far; your question is not much clear to us

Comment: Marked down because showed no effort or example to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `date`,name FROM sample_table WHERE `DATE` IS NULL OR `DATE` = '0000-00-00'
```

NOTE: DATE is a reserved word so needs to be encased in backticks to be treated as a column name. I would strongly advise changing your column names due to this. What is it the date of?

Comment: I mean this date is completion_date and i want 0 everywhere , where there is no record of completion date against name for ex -

Name Date
Ram Null
Shyam 0000-00-00
Heena 2015-12-23

expected result will be - 

Ram - 0
Shyam - 0
Heena - 1

Comment: PHP is irrelevant here. The backticks are part of MySQL syntax.

Comment: Fair enough @Zurahn, answer updated. I knew it was one or the other but at time of writing wasn't going to dig around for ten minutes to confirm. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure,but you can try:

```
select name, case when CAST(IFNULL(`Date`,'0000-00-00') as varchar(50))=
'0000-00-00' then 0 else 1 End from My_Table_Name
```